# Realm Sync Configuration getting exception

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using Realm first time. I want to sync both server data with mobile app and vice versa.
So I setup Realm object server and trying to implement sync with following code

```
SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword("rajesh@gmail.com", "rajesh", false);

    SyncUser.loginAsync(myCredentials, BaseApplication.SERVER_URL, new SyncUser.Callback<SyncUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SyncUser result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: "+result.getIdentity());

            SyncConfiguration realmConfig = new SyncConfiguration
                    .Builder(SyncUser.currentUser(), BaseApplication.REALM_URL)
                    .name("MyDb")
                    .build();
            Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", error);
            Log.i(TAG, "onError: "+error.getErrorCode());
        }
    });
```

Success block is executing but with Sync configuration getting following error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
at io.realm.SyncConfiguration$Builder.validateAndSet(SyncConfiguration.java:545)
at io.realm.SyncConfiguration$Builder.<init>(SyncConfiguration.java:458)
at io.realm.SyncConfiguration$Builder.<init>(SyncConfiguration.java:444)
at com.examkida.Activities.MainActivity$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:150)
at com.example.Activities.MainActivity$2.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:144)
at io.realm.SyncUser$Request$3.run(SyncUser.java:691)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: What is your Realm URL ( BaseApplication.REALM_URL ) like? The failure seems to occur because the evaluated path has no `/`s in it, which is odd.

Comment: Realm Url : realm://serverip:9080/~/myapp

Comment: What happens if you remove `.name("MyDb")`?

Comment: Actually, I tried without .name before but got error so I put .name

Comment: My best guess is that the ` BaseApplication.REALM_URL` is not what you think it is, because the code in question only fails if the url contains no `/`.

Comment: Here is my url copy from code :  public static final String REALM_URL = "realm://51.255.50.000:9080/~/examforum"; only trailing zeros change. This can be wrong, I am new to Realm, Where can crosscheck URL

Comment: I tested `realm://51.255.50.000:9080/~/examforum` and it works fine for me,  so I'm guessing you in some cases are not using that URL? But if you are able to reproduce this in a sample project, I'll be happy to take a look.